# __git_ps1 not found when su username with Bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh

My current user, firstuser has a default shell of `/bin/sh`

My `.profile` is one line:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bash_profile ] && . $HOME/.bash_profile
```

My `.bash_profile` is one line:

```
[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc
```

My `.bashrc` has the following code:

```
[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion
export PS1='$(__git_ps1) \$  '
```

Here's the issue:

```
$  su seconduser
Password:
bash: __git_ps1: command not found
$
```

Note:
seconduser has a shell of `/bin/bash`

What I want is all my customizations from firstuser to be carried into the shell of seconduser.

Comment: What happens if you run `__git_ps1` on your command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is setting the prompt variable `PS1` to `$(__git_ps1) \$` literally.  And your shell is interpreting it while displaying the prompt.

`$(__git_ps1)` tries to run `__git_ps1` as a command and grab its output - this [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).  Are you sure you wanted it that way?  In that case, make sure that it is a valid command and it's in the PATH.

Comment: It's the way the git prompt is meant to be integrated into `PS1`, see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh – however, it looks like the OP hasn't installed git in such a way that the right files are sourced and `__git_ps1` is made available.

Comment: After taking a look at the link, I went with option 3b) Setting the contents of the PROMPT_COMMAND variable seems like a safer approach on OS X especially if multiple tiers of privilege escalation are involved. 
Thanks @BenjaminW.